# Storing & Retrieving Images

Tags: java, mysql, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

I am doing some project for an institute using JSF, MYSQL.

There are many places where images needs to be stored. 70% of the application is based on images. I read on SO for storing images in mysql, however I found that storing images in mysql is bad idea and got some alternate.

I have three option

**Option 1** : Store image in mysql

**Option 2** : Store image in local file system

**Option 3** : Store image at any hosting website (like amazon s3).

I can't use Option 3 as institute don't want to store images over internet. They want to make local system.

I was thinking of using Option 2, however I am curious what if tomorrow my server got crashed? Also files from the server can be deleted by any one. (**Security issue**)

So option I left is Option 1, storing images in mysql.

Just curious, is there any disadvantages in storing images in MySQL?

Shall I go ahead with Option 1 for storing images? I am really concerned.

---

Everyone should read below great post.

### [Huge File Storage in Database instead of File System](http://akashkava.com/blog/127/huge-file-storage-in-database-instead-of-file-system/)

Comment: @juergend : Even I was reading this link and I was about to post. But I am just curious, what to choose. On this link, I am seeing option 2 would be right choice.. However, I have concern. Your input on this...

Comment: this is bit different question, no need to vote for exact duplicate. Please read my answer..

Comment: Your 'answer' was moved to the question because it's not an answer. Few reason why: 1) the post doesn't describe how the link solves the problem, 2) if that link goes down, this question is now not answered *and* useless. If you have an answer, post it as an answer -- but do not just post a link as an answer.