# Including jsp in jsf page

Tags: jsp, jsf-2, include, jspinclude

Below is what I have in JSP page

`example.jsp`

```
<html>
    <body>
        //report using mysql connection
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to include this page in one of my jsf page. How could I do that?

I tried with below, however I get error as `javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /detailedReports.jsp: Error Traced[line: 1] The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.`

Code I tried is

```
<h:form>
    <ui:include src="detailedReports.jsp" />   
</h:form>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you have an answer, it should be posted *as an answer*, not added to the text of the question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker : Once before I had received feedback from moderator to put answer in question only, hence I put in question itself. Now I added answer...

Comment: I'd be *very* interested to know who told you that, since we have FAQs on meta that tell how to handle this. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions

Comment: @GeorgeStocker : Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285363/storing-retrieving-images) question of my own. casperOne delete my answer and posted the same in question...

Comment: @GeorgeStocker : also when you reply please mind adding @ FahimParkar before answer so that I will get notification that someone send me some note.. else I won't be able to read your reply. I am saying this because I didn't get any notification for your "I'd be very inter....." note...

Comment: the notification system may be slower, but the system removes the @OP name whenever it's appended. This is your post, you'll receive notifications on all answers and comments to it, regardless of who they're directed at.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker : okay, I take my words back. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used omnifaces for the same.

```
<o:resourceInclude path="detailedReports.jsp" />
```

did the trick....